# Android TextView append() method causing NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am using append() method to append text to a textview named "lectureName" (as given in activity file below) but its giving me null pointer exception.

I have ensured that :

1. I have set correct xml layout in setContentView()
2. Layout file contains required Text View with id "lectureName". I have set it with text "Lecture :" in XML file to which I want to append name of the lecture dynamically.
3. Reference to the text view (i.e. variable lectureName in activity) is not null.

But still I cant figure out why I am getting null pointer exception at lectureName.append() method. I came across similer issues about setText() method on StackOverflow but coulnt get any clue.

My Layout file : activity_class_attendance_info.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/className"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

     <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/className"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">  

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/lectureName"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Lecture :" />

              <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/attDate"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Date :" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">             

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/attTime"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Time :" />             
            </TableRow>           
        </TableLayout>     
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/totalStudents"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/info_table"
         android:text="Total Students :" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/presentStudents"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/totalStudents"
         android:text="Present Students :" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/absentStudents"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/presentStudents"
         android:text="Absent Students :" />


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/presentStudentsRollNos"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/absentStudents" 
         android:text="Present Students Roll Nos. :"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity File :

```
public class ClassAttendanceInfoActivity extends Activity {
    TextView className,lectureName,attDate,attTime,presentStudents,
        absentStudents,totalStudents,presentStudentsRollNos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_attendance_info);

        className = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.className);
        lectureName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lectureName); 
        attDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attDate);
        attTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attTime);
        presentStudents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presentStudents);
        absentStudents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.absentStudents);
        totalStudents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalStudents);
        presentStudentsRollNos  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presentStudentsRollNos);

        ClassAttendance attendance = (ClassAttendance) GlobalClass.objectToBePassed;
        GlobalClass.objectToBePassed = null;

        // to check whether error causing lectureName TextView is null
            if(lectureName == null)
            Log.e("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","lectureName is null!!");
        else
            Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","lectureName is not null :"+lectureName.getText());

        //set values
        className.setText(attendance.getClassObject().getClassName());
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","className:"+className.getText());

            // Getting ERROR in following line --->
        lectureName.append(attendance.getLectureName()); 
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","lectureName"+lectureName.getText());

            attDate.append(attendance.getAttDate());
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","attDate"+attDate.getText());
        attTime.append(attendance.getAttTime());
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","attTime"+attTime.getText());
        presentStudents .append(String.valueOf(attendance.getPresentCount()));
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","presentStudents"+presentStudents.getText());
        absentStudents.append(String.valueOf(attendance.getAbsentCount()));
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","absentStudents"+absentStudents.getText());
        totalStudents.append(String.valueOf(attendance.getTotalCount()));
        Log.v("ClassAttendanceInfoActivity","totalStudents"+totalStudents.getText());

        ArrayList<Integer> presentStudentsRollList = attendance.getPresentStudentsRollList();

        //generate roll list string
        String rollList=null;       
        for(int i=0;i<presentStudentsRollList.size();i++){
            rollList = rollList + "," + presentStudentsRollList.get(i);
        }
        presentStudentsRollNos.append(rollList);

    }
}
```

LogCat :

```
06-28 17:47:26.719: V/MyClassesFragment(6037): Jumping to ClassAttInfoActivity    
06-28 17:47:26.749: V/ActivityThread(6037): Launching activity com.example.rolltest.ClassAttendanceInfoActivity with config { 
scale=1.0 imsi=405/13 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=10}    
06-28 17:47:26.759: V/ClassAttendanceInfoActivity(6037): lectureName is not null :Lecture :    
06-28 17:47:26.759: V/ClassAttendanceInfoActivity(6037): className :gg-22Yearty    
06-28 17:47:26.759: W/dalvikvm(6037): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40224560)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.rolltest/com.example.rolltest.ClassAttendanceInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:875)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:2295)    
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at com.example.rolltest.ClassAttendanceInfoActivity.onCreate
(ClassAttendanceInfoActivity.java:40)
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-28 17:47:26.769: E/AndroidRuntime(6037):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why are using for Class Name attendance.getClassObject() and for Lecture Name attendance object ?

Comment: I have try you code with demo data and it works like charm so i think problem in you data holder class and if you know more specific error then add try catch to each data get line.

Comment: Thanks @Haresh for your effort ! My problem is solved, it was just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attendance.getLectureName()` is returning null to `append` method, Thus, NullPointerException is generated !

Comment: Yes you are correct ! I forgot to set lectureName value in constructor. My bad !!! Thanks alot !